# AttributeError: 'OdbStep' object has no attribute 'fieldRegions'

Tags: python

I'm just new in abaqus scripting and want to extract data from .odb for some specific points.I wrote the number of my desired nodes in a .txt file and the following python script. But get this error:

AttributeError: 'OdbStep' object has no attribute 'fieldRegions'

Here is my script:

```
from abaqus import*
from abaqusConstants import*
from odbAccess import*
B=[]
C=open('node_number.txt','r')
cont1=0
for line in C.readlines():
   B.append(line)
   cont1=cont1+1
R=open('Termal Results','w')
odb=openOdb(path='half-initial1400.odb')
mystep=odb.steps['Step-12']
cont2=0
for Nodes in B:
   region=mystep.fieldRegions['half model-initial1400'+str(B[0][:])]
   variable=region.fieldOutputs['NT11'].data
   for time,data in variable[1 :]:
      R.write(data)
    R.write('\n')
    cont2=cont2+1
R.close()
C.close()
```

Also, I think the problem maybe relates to the .txt file which I wrote the node's number in it.I just wrote:
1
2
3
4

Does anybody Know whats wrong?

Best regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The error message is pointing you in the direction you need to go. Check out what the members of `odb.steps` are. Looks like `fieldRegions` isn't one of them.